# why browser isnt storing a cookie created in a subdomain, in the referer subdomain?

Tags: cookies

i'm facing a few problems when i authenticate usign cookies to store the token, those cookies should be delivered between subdomains, for example, i have my auth code deployed in a subdomain named **services.mydomain.co** and my frontend in  subdomain named **apps.mydomain.co**,
when someone authenticates, then my auth code creates a cookie with the tag Domain like this: **Domain=.mydomain.co** in order to enable it to be delivered between all subdomains of **mydomain.co**, but the cruel reallity is that it is not working, even the browser isn't storing the cookie.

the cookie it's successful delivered in response header after authenticate but the browser isn't storing it.

im creating the cookie this way:`Set-Cookie: myKey=myKeyValue;path=/;httpOnly;Max-Age=1555520000;Domain=.mydomain.co;sameSite=none`

hope someone could geve me an advice and sorry for bad english.

Answer (score 1):

From your example, you are setting `SameSite=None` without `Secure`. This is invalid and browsers (Chrome, Edge, Firefox, etc.) will begin rejecting this.

However, you should check DevTools in Chrome on your site to see the specific error. You can check both the Console and individual requests in the Network tab to see issues with a given cookie.

You can find more detail on https://www.chromium.org/updates/same-site/test-debug